# More elegant, simpler way to convert code point to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, lua

For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7983574/405017) I created the following Lua code that converts a Unicode code point to a UTF-8 character string. Is there a better way to do this (in Lua 5.1+)? "Better" in this case means *"drastically more efficient, or—preferably—far fewer lines of code"*.

Note: I'm not really asking for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) of this algorithm; I'm asking for a better algorithm (or built-in library).

```lua
do
  local bytebits = {
    {0x7F,{0,128}},
    {0x7FF,{192,32},{128,64}},
    {0xFFFF,{224,16},{128,64},{128,64}},
    {0x1FFFFF,{240,8},{128,64},{128,64},{128,64}}
  }
  function utf8(decimal)
    local charbytes = {}
    for b,lim in ipairs(bytebits) do
      if decimal<=lim[1] then
        for i=b,1,-1 do
          local prefix,max = lim[i+1][1],lim[i+1][2]
          local mod = decimal % max
          charbytes[i] = string.char( prefix + mod )
          decimal = ( decimal - mod ) / max
        end
        break
      end
    end
    return table.concat(charbytes)
  end
end

c=utf8(0x24)     print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") --> $ is 1 bytes.
c=utf8(0xA2)     print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") --> ¢ is 2 bytes.
c=utf8(0x20AC)   print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") --> € is 3 bytes.  
c=utf8(0xFFFF)   print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") -->  is 3 bytes.
c=utf8(0x10000)  print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") -->  is 4 bytes.
c=utf8(0x24B62)  print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") -->  is 4 bytes.
```

---

*I feel like there ought to be a way to get rid of the whole `bytebits` predefined table and loop just to find the matching entry. Looping from the back I could continually `%64` and add `128` to form the continuation bytes until the value was below 128, but I can't figure out how to elegantly generate the `0`/`110`/`1110`/`11110` preamble to add on.*

---

**Edit**: Here's a slightly better reworking, with a speed optimization. This is not an acceptable answer, though, since the algorithm is still basically the same idea and about the same amount of code.

```
do
  local bytemarkers = { {0x7FF,192}, {0xFFFF,224}, {0x1FFFFF,240} }
  function utf8(decimal)
    if decimal<128 then return string.char(decimal) end
    local charbytes = {}
    for bytes,vals in ipairs(bytemarkers) do
      if decimal<=vals[1] then
        for b=bytes+1,2,-1 do
          local mod = decimal%64
          decimal = (decimal-mod)/64
          charbytes[b] = string.char(128+mod)
        end
        charbytes[1] = string.char(vals[2]+decimal)
        break
      end
    end
    return table.concat(charbytes)
  end
end
```

Comment: Attempting to do the loop through, my final comment above describes a flawed algorithm. For example, Unicode [code point `0x10000`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10000/index.htm) requires four bytes in UTF-8. After shifting right by 12 bits (two `/64`) the original value is down to just 16. It seems like some hard-coded knowledge about the relationship between the starting value, the number of bytes, and the initial byte's preamble is basically required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking about speed, the usage pattern in a real world scenario is very important. But here, we're in a vacuum, so let's proceed anyway.

This algorithm is probably what you're looking for when you say you thing you ought to be able to get rid of *bytebits*:

```
do
  local string_char = string.char
  function utf8(cp)
    if cp < 128 then
      return string_char(cp)
    end
    local s = ""
    local prefix_max = 32
    while true do
      local suffix = cp % 64
      s = string_char(128 + suffix)..s
      cp = (cp - suffix) / 64
      if cp < prefix_max then
        return string_char((256 - (2 * prefix_max)) + cp)..s
      end
      prefix_max = prefix_max / 2
    end
  end
end
```

It also includes some other optimizations which aren't particularly interesting, and for me is about 2x as fast as your optimized given code. (As a bonus, it should work all the way up to U+7FFFFFFF as well.)

If we want to micro-optimize even more, the loop can be unrolled to:

```
do
  local string_char = string.char
  function utf8_unrolled(cp)
    if cp < 128 then
      return string_char(cp)
    end
    local suffix = cp % 64
    local c4 = 128 + suffix
    cp = (cp - suffix) / 64
    if cp < 32 then
      return string_char(192 + cp, c4)
    end
    suffix = cp % 64
    local c3 = 128 + suffix
    cp = (cp - suffix) / 64
    if cp < 16 then
      return string_char(224 + cp, c3, c4)
    end
    suffix = cp % 64
    cp = (cp - suffix) / 64
    return string_char(240 + cp, 128 + suffix, c3, c4)
  end
end
```

This is about 5x as fast as your optimized code, but wholly inelegant. I think the main gains are not having to store intermediate results on the heap and having fewer function calls.

However, the fastest (as far as I can find) approach is not to do the calculation at all:

```
do
  local lookup = {}
  for i=0,0x1FFFFF do
    lookup[i]=calculate_utf8(i)
  end  
  function utf8(cp)
    return lookup[cp]
  end
end
```

This is about 30x as fast as your optimized code which may qualify as "drastically more efficient" (although the memory usage is ridiculous). However, it is also not interesting. (A good compromise in some cases would be to use memoization.)

Of course, any pure c implementation is likely to be faster than any calculation done in Lua.

Comment: An excellent point about memoization. I'll definitely be adding that, thanks! I'll definitely analyze your algorithm and if it pans out award the acceptance.

Comment: For what it's worth, even without unrolling and memoization your code tests as about 4x faster than mine on my machine. (Using a non-real-world even distribution of 1000000 random code points between `1` and `0x10FFFF`, and also between `1` and `0x20AC`.) And I did confirm that both our answers produce the same results for all code points up to `0x10FFFF` (RFC 3629). Well done.

Answer (score 3):

Lua 5.3 provides [a basic UTF-8 library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5), among which the function [`utf8.char`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.char) is what you are looking for:

> Receives zero or more integers, converts each one to its corresponding UTF-8 byte sequence and returns a string with the concatenation of all these sequences.

```
c = utf8.char(0x24)     print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") --> $ is 1 bytes.
c = utf8.char(0xA2)     print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") --> ¢ is 2 bytes.
c = utf8.char(0x20AC)   print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") --> € is 3 bytes.  
c = utf8.char(0xFFFF)   print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") -->  is 3 bytes.
c = utf8.char(0x10000)  print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") -->  is 4 bytes.
c = utf8.char(0x24B62)  print(c.." is "..#c.." bytes.") -->  is 4 bytes.
```

Comment: That algorithm probably meets the question asker's criteria.

Comment: @TomBlodget That meets all my criteria except, sadly, the requirement for Lua 5.1 support.

Comment: @Phrogz You can rewrite it in Lua, though without the bit32 library it doesn't look as elegant.