# Lua hex string to ASCII?

Tags: lua, hex, ascii

I'm wanting to convert a hex string to ASCII character, (for the game ROBLOX).

Here's the page for the ASCII icon:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ba/index.htm

Although I'm not even sure that Lua supports that icon.

**EDIT:**

Turns out ROBLOX doesn't support UTF-8 symbols at all due to their ['chat filtering'.](https://github.com/Anaminus/roblox-bug-tracker/issues/771)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983574/how-to-write-a-unicode-symbol-in-lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in Lua are encoding-agnostic and you can just use the character in the string:

```
print"►"
```

Alternatively:

- Output the Unicode code directly with `print"\u{25BA}"`.
- Output the UTF-8 encoding directly with `print"\xE2\x96\xBA"`.
- Output the UTF-8 encoding directly with `print"\226\150\186"`.

Comment: Looks like ROBLOX doesn't support \u for strings. I don't suppose there is an alternative?

Comment: And they also don't support UTF-8, seen [here](https://gyazo.com/4f1b9180b1bdb79677bc97d432f9ea97) thanks anyway I guess. Also by directly printing it when saving the code it will automatically turn into a ?.